# CanActivate causing throttling history state error

Tags: angular

Whenever I navigate to `/about` page my app ends up in an infinite loop with the error `Throttling history state changes to prevent the browser from hanging`.

Whenever I navigate to `/` page my app doesn't navigate to `dashboard`, it just displays a blank page.

I am expecting my page to navigate to `/dashboard` if a token is found and `/home` or `/` when it isn't.

Furthermore, I would like the remaining pages linked below to be inaccessible (apart from dashboard), if a token is found.

How can I fix this?

**app.routing.component.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'careers', component: CareersComponent },
  { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent },
  { path: 'legal', component: LegalComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'press', component: PressComponent },
  { path: 'markets', component: MarketsComponent },
  { path: 'markets/:symbol', component: PriceComponent },
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
  { path: 'status', component: StatusComponent },
  { path: 'services', component: ServicesComponent },
  { path: 'support', component: SupportComponent },
  { path: 'support/account-management', component: AccountManagementComponent },
  { path: 'support/transactions', component: TransactionsComponent },
  { path: 'support/payment-methods', component: PaymentMethodsComponent },
  { path: 'support/security', component: SecurityComponent },
  { path: 'support/task-administration', component: TaskAdministrationComponent },
  { path: 'support/wallet-services', component: WalletServicesComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled' });
  }
}
```

**auth.guard.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router) {
  }

  canActivate(
    _next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    _state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    if (this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {
      this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
      if (environment.production === false) {
        console.log('Token found, redirecting to dashboard');
      }
      return true;
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(['home']);
      if (environment.production === false) {
        console.log('Token not found, redirecting to home');
      }
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

**auth.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(private myRoute: Router) { }

  getToken() {
    return localStorage.getItem('token');
  }

  isLoggedIn() {
    return this.getToken() !== null;
  }

  logout() {
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
    this.myRoute.navigate(['login']);
  }
}
```

Comment: Only navigate to a route if it is not equal to your current route,

Comment: Sorry I don’t understand. How does that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I think you need to put the wildcard last:

```
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' }
```

Second, if you want a page to be inaccessibly depending on a token, you should add a guard on those pages.

Third, you have `/` mapped to the `HomeComponent`, so that will never redirect to the `DashboardComponent`.

Fourth, I believe the infinite loop is because your `AuthGuard` redirects to `/dashboard`. That path is guarded by `AuthGuard`, which redirects to `/dashboard`, etc. etc. You shouldn't redirect to a path which is guarded by the same guard that does the redirecting.

What I think you should do, is split your guards into two:

- one guard for `/home` to redirect to dashboard if there is a token. This guard should *not* redirect to home if there is no token, because that is already the current path!
- one guard for the `/dashboard` and those other paths to redirect to home if there is no token. This guard should *not* redirect to dashboard if there is a token!